# Tkinter - Label Text Not Displaying Until After Program Runs

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm new to Tkinter. I am testing something that I thought would be simple and straightforward but I'm missing something here.

**Expected behavior**: Push button, show 'Starting...' label text, wait 5 seconds, show 'Finished' label text.

**Actual behavior**: Push button, wait 5 seconds, show 'Starting...' label text, show 'Finished' label text.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time


def main():
    global label1
    global label2
    label1['text'] = "Starting..."

    time.sleep(5)
    # just using time.sleep(5) to simplify this example, 
    # I'm actually doing a lot of work here not really sleeping

    label2['text'] = "Finished!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Parse and Load Kompass Review Period Data')
    root.geometry("350x350")
    tk.Label(root, text="\nParse and Load Data").pack(anchor=tk.W, padx=50)
    btn = tk.Button(root, text="GO", command=main).pack(anchor=tk.W, padx=50)

    label1 = tk.Label(text="")
    label1.pack()
    label2 = tk.Label(text="")
    label2.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

I'm not sure why the 'Starting...' label text doesn't display before the time.sleep(5). Any ideas out there?

Comment: It's because `time.sleep(5)` puts the application to sleep. When it's sleeping, it can't update the display. There are _many_ questions about tkinter and time.sleep on this site.

Comment: Ok so I just threw time.sleep() in there to make the example less complicated for this post. In place of the time.sleep() I'm actually doing a lot of stuff (connecting to sql db, pulling data, munging/cleaning it, re-writing to another sql db, etc). The point being, no matter what I've tried, I can't get text to display before the work is done and of all the questions/answers on here that I've read through haven't helped me solve this yet.

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me every time. I spend hours googling and stackoverflowing, looking for an answer. Then I finally post a question and 30 minutes later, I've found something that helps me figure it out.

You have to use root.update() after the first label1['text'] = "Starting...".

I'm not sure the reason behind why this works exactly but it works. I'm guessing that this updates the frame before continuing on through the code or something like that?

```
import tkinter as tk
import time


def main():
    global label1
    global label2
    global root
    label1['text'] = "Starting..."

    root.update()
    time.sleep(5)
    # just using time.sleep(5) to simplify this example, 
    # I'm actually doing a lot of work here not really sleeping

    label2['text'] = "Finished!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Parse and Load Kompass Review Period Data')
    root.geometry("350x350")
    tk.Label(root, text="\nParse and Load Data").pack(anchor=tk.W, padx=50)
    btn = tk.Button(root, text="GO", command=main).pack(anchor=tk.W, padx=50)

    label1 = tk.Label(text="")
    label1.pack()
    label2 = tk.Label(text="")
    label2.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```